# Hint for the following integral

Tags: integration

$$
\int{{\rm d}z \over \left(\,1 - a^{2} + a^{2}z^{2}\,\right)^{3/2}}
$$

From where shall I start solving this integral ?. Any hints for the above integral ?.

Comment: Hello - please tell us what you have tried: Hove you done or seen a similar integral, e.g. with the exponent $1/2$ instead of $3/2$, or with a specific value of $a$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider how you would solve
$$
\int \dfrac{dz}{(b^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}
$$

You would use $z=b \tan \theta$

$$
\int \dfrac{b \sec^2 \theta}{b^3(\sec^2 \theta)^\frac{3}{2}}
$$

Can you proceed from here?

Edited to add: Since your application requires something of the form
$$
\int \dfrac{dz}{(z^2-b^2)^\frac{3}{2}}
$$

You can use the hyperbolic function substitution $z=b \coth u$

$dz = -\operatorname{csch}^2 {u} \; du$. The integral becomes
$$
\int \dfrac{-b \operatorname{csch}^2 {u} \; du}{b^3 \operatorname{csch}^3 {u}} =
-\frac{1}{b^2}\int \sinh u du = 
-\frac{1}{b^2} \cosh u
$$

etc.

Comment: I get $\int \frac{\sec^{2}\Theta d\Theta}{(1-a^{2}\sec^{2}\Theta)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$. What shall I do next?

Comment: @bpr3003 No no, divide by $a^2$ and write the term inside the root as $z^2 + (1/a^2 - 1)$. When $|a|<1$, you can write the term inside as $z^2+b^2$. When $|a|>1$, you can write the term inside the root as $z^2-b^2$. In the second case, you'll need a different substitution.

Comment: It's an integral from my Electrodynamics book where $a=\frac{v}{c}$. For my problem |a|>1 so I think I would go with the latter. Thanks for the help @user_of_math

Comment: @bpr3003 Ok, in that case you'll need to use $z=b \coth x$